# How to export database with location information of technosphere

Tags: brightway

Thank you for developing such a great tool for LCA researchers! I am new here and have a problem exporting database with location information of the technosphere from the Ecoinvent database.

Here is the code I used:

```
import os
import brightway2 as bw
import bw2io as bi
importer = bi.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer('C://Users/.../ecoinvent391_cutoff_ecoSpold02/datasets','e391_')
importer.apply_strategies()
importer.statistics()
importer.write_excel()
```

and the database written in Excel is like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Two89.png)

I want to export data with the location of each activity, especially for the technosphere, which is "unknown" in the Excel but exists in the database when looking into ActivityBrowser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fim6m.png)

Could anyone give some hints in revising strategies or somewhere in the functions? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The command `importer.write_excel()` is only used to export the current state of the data on the `importer` object for debugging. If you want to export the database, write it first using `importer.write_database()`. You can then iterate through the individual datasets and write them to whatever format you want, or try [`bw2io.export.write_lci_excel`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/main/bw2io/export/excel.py#L220C13-L220C13) to export to a standardized format.